# font awesome: retrieve css of pseudo element displays a small rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I am trying to retrieve the CSS value of font awesome pseudo element. 
This is the css:

```
.pe-icon--check:before {
    content: '\f00c';
}
```

I use this query

```
var symb = window.getComputedStyle($('.pe-icon--check').get(0), ':before').getPropertyValue('content');
```

But the result I get is a small rectangle ``. The value I need is `\f00c`.
Could someone please help me fix this?

Comment: what would be the result for console.log(symb); ?

Comment: Have you included the font properly and followed the correct folder set up? Are you using it locally? it has to be exact or it fails, like you're seeing

Comment: @ymz - the result of console.log(symb) is: 

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - The icon loads properly on the page and there are no errors, it is able to identify the icon. To retrieve the css 'content' is where I face the issue. I want \f00c and not the small rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solution worked!!

```
var content = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.pe-icon--check'),':before').getPropertyValue('content');
```

```
function entityForSymbolInContainer(character) {
    var code = character.replace(/"/g, '').charCodeAt(0);
    var codeHex = code.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    while (codeHex.length < 4) {
        codeHex = "0" + codeHex;
    }
    return "\\" + codeHex + ";";
}
```